# Updating code to include error handling and a worker thread

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm newbie to android development. I'll like the code below(for querying a media collection) to be updated to include a `try` and `catch` block for error handling,and the `query()` method called in a worker thread.

```
public void getAllImages(){
        Uri imageCollection;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            imageCollection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
        } else {
            imageCollection = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }
 
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE
        };
 
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
 
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(imageCollection , projection, null, null, sortOrder);
        int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED);
        int sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE);
 
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
            int duration = cursor.getInt(dateColumn);
            int size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn);
            Uri uriImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(imageCollection, ""+ id);
            ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
            imageModel.setImage(uriImage);
            imageList.add(imageModel);
        }
        cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above the `Cursor` will not throw an exception in its current format. Even
`MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);` wont throw an exception due to `MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL` not being `null`.

Your next step is to  wrap the rest of the code in a `try-catch-finally` and then wrap that in a `Thread.run()` call.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(imageCollection, projection, null, null, sortOrder);
            int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED);
            int sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
                int duration = cursor.getInt(dateColumn);
                int size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn);
                Uri uriImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(imageCollection, "" + id);
                ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
                imageModel.setImage(uriImage);
                imageList.add(imageModel);
            }
            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
//Start the thread
thread.start();
```

Now there are plenty of other ways to use background threads that produce better flows than just using `Thread`, including `Worker`*(from jetpack)*, `RxJava`, and `Guava`. Also `coroutines` if using Kotlin.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained

Comment: I tried the code... The images are not loading,and no error messages is given. The original code is working.